# Minified component stack trace in create-react-app (dev mode)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, stack-trace, source-maps

Running `create-react-app` in **development** mode:

Why do my console errors link to minified code chunks? I thought I remember CRA being able to show the source mapped files.

[image: console error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the error was thrown by one of the dependencies you used. When you install a package, you get a minified-production-build version on your node_modules. We can see from the stack traces, that the error was located in `vendors~main.chunk.js`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).